# Bootstrap 3 Cover sample - header and nav overlay content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a very simple page using the Bootstrap Cover example. The site name and nav bar are fixed. When i scroll the content the site title and nav bar look superimposed over teh top of the content. Any ideas? The site is http://southbayrepairsolutions.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was change the example from a masthead at the top to a navbar that is fixed at the top. That seems to have fixed the issue.